# Execute loop inside your variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do like this. ?

```
var html = '<div class="list-group">'+
      $.each(val,function(key,value){
             'value: ' +  value + '<br/>'
      })
+'</div>';
```

I am expecting the answer to be like this:

```
<div class="list-group">
    value: value1
    value: value2
    value: value3
</div>
```

But why I am getting this result?

```
<div class="list-group">
    [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me if what I am doing is absolutely wrong.?

How should I do the code to get my expected result ?
Thank you!

Comment: store value: value1... in a variable and then put that variable in `div`

Comment: it looks like your val is a list of objects, not strings.. so, the question is: what you want to print out of these objects? ex: 'value: ' +  value.text + '<br/>'

Comment: @pumpkinzzz: Were that the case you'd still see "value: " and a "<br/>"; he does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're concatenating the result of calling `$.each()`, which in the case of jQuery, returns the entire list `val`. What you want to do is call `$.map()`, which returns an array of results of the callback for every item of `val`. You then need to `join()` the strings together. Should look like this (untested):

```
var html = '<div class="list-group">'+
      $.map(val,function(key,value){
           return 'value: ' +  value + '<br/>';
      }).join()
+'</div>';
```

Comment: doesn't `map` gives parameters as `(value,key)` not `(key,value)`

Comment: is `.join()` necessary? I tried not including `.join` but it still works

Comment: @LLawliet it is necessary, because `map` returns an `array`

Comment: It seems that the result is still the same when there is join or none.. ? :D

Comment: @LLawliet it'll be calling `Array.toString()` and both outputs same `join()` & `toString()` for Array.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$.map()` in this context ignore `$.each()`,

```
var html  = '<div class="list-group">';
html += $.map(val,function(key,value){
            return 'value: ' +  value + '<br/>'
});
html+ = '</div>';
```